# DesignPattern to handle pojos

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a file parser that reads text file line by line and creates a 'Event'   object that represent the line.

There are 3 types of 'Event' so I created 4 pojos.
`EventTypeA`, `EventTypeB`, `EventTypeC`, `EventTypeD` that extend a `BaseEvent` that I push to an arraylist.

Pojos have nothing in common, as each pojo (event) has different set of fields.

Now I have an event handler that should handle all the events in the list based on the type.

I want the best elegant way to process them. I identified four options:

1. The obvious approach is via polymorphism, but those  are pojos and I
   don't want to put any business code there.
2. The second option is simply to check `instanceof` and casting
   `BaseEvent` to concrete `EventType` to, but it's not elegant.
3. Third option is to add `type` field (enum) to pojo and then do a
   'switch' checks (+ the casting) , but it's also not elegant.
4. Fourth option would be to create a hashmap, where key would be the
   name of the pojo class, and the value will a instance of class with
   code that handles it.   I don't like that as well.

What can you suggest? 
Thanks

Comment: Is the event handler expecting to call the same methods independent of the type of pojo? Ie can you expose the relevant behavior via an interface?

Comment: I believe I can, but again, it will require me in some way to link the concrete implementation of the handler to the right pojo.

Comment: I think the pattern "abstract factory" fits your problem.

Comment: I would  add a handler member in Event, as well as a handle method calling handler.handle().  The handler instance can be passed at event instantiation, and there you already have event type specific code. Handlers would be subclasses of an abstract Handler class declaring the handle() method, which the subclasses would implement.

Comment: I mean that each EventType could implement `handle()`, an abstract method on `Event`. The event handler iterates the `List<Event>` calling `handle()` on each.

Comment: @ Roberto Attias @Nic, I wan't to avoid that, I don't want my pojos to know nothing about handlers.

Comment: @Nic why put handling code into the EventType? That's none of its business.

Comment: I misunderstood what EventType was.

Comment: Maybe you can go along this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/

Comment: You know that POJO just means "Plain Old Java Object", meaning there is nothing magical about it, and you shouldn't be treating it as something separate from "real" Java code.

Comment: @shivesh I think you have a some higher level design problem which made this kind of a problem to happen. Can you please explain your scenario specifically??

Comment: @RealSkeptic In that case shivesh's point makes sense I guess. What he is trying is to avoid business logic from pojos. It makes sense right? :))

Comment: @SupunWijerathne And where will you have your business logic other than Java objects?

Comment: @RealSkeptic There seems to be a misconception on behalf of the OP that Listener / Event**Handler** code must be inside the Event**Type** class ... which is of course not correct.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135051/discussion-on-question-by-shivesh-designpattern-to-handle-pojos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you want is the "Visitor":

https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor

I'm using it in a parser that I'm writing. I have an abstract class "AbstractNode", and a concrete class for each node type in the abstract syntax tree (BinaryOperationNode, AssignStatementNode, etc.). My parser gets a reference to the root node of the tree and then process each node sequentially. The Visitor pattern helps me to avoid writing a massive chain of if instanceof/else if(...).

The drawback is having to update the Visitor interface and each class that implements it each time that a new node type is created.

Comment: "and each class that implements it" - you could avoid that with an Adapter.

Comment: Visitor interface looks good, but my heart still aching a little bit seeing 'accept' method in each pojo

Answer (score 4):

There many possible solutions to this problem. However, the constraints you gave discard many of them. I think that the main issue here is trying to avoid to modify existing code each time a new `Event` type will be developed.

One possible solution is to use a *[Chain of responsibility](http://rcardin.github.io/design/programming/java/scala/di/2016/12/07/code-looks-like-a-chain.html)* on handlers. Define a common interface for handlers:

```
interface EventHandler {
    void handle(BasicEvent event);
}
```

You will have a concrete handler implementation for each type of Event. Then, collect all the events in a common processor.

```
class EventProcessor {
    private List<EventHandler> handlers;
    public EventProcessor(List<EventHandler> handlers) {
        this.handlers = handlers;
    }

    public void process(BasicEvent event) {
        handlers.forEach(handler -> handler.handle(event));
    }
}
```

In this way, every event will be processed only by the proper handler. Others handler will discard the event. Each time a new event will be develop, it will be sufficient to develop the relative handler and to add it to the chain.

There are many variant of this pattern. IMHO, this is the simplier one.

**EDIT**

For sake of completeness, if you can remove the requirement you stated at point

> 4. *Fourth option would be to create a hashmap, where key would be the name of   the pojo class, and the value will a instance of class with code that handles it*

me and others (see comments below) think that the best approach should be really to have a dedicated `Map` for handlers.

```
class EventProcessor {
    private Map<EventType, EventHandler> handlers;

    public void process(BasicEvent event) {
        handlers
            .get(event.getType)
            .handle(event);
    }
}
```

The most important fact is that the above map `handlers` has to be built automatically, perhaps using dependency injection. Doing so, when you will add a new type of *event*, you can guarantee to not violate the *Open Closed Principle* of SOLID.

Cheers.

Comment: CoR is generally for sharing responsibility among a set of similar entities. In this case AFAIU there is nothing to share right? :))

Comment: The GoF intent is to "Avoid coupling the sender of a request to its reciever by giving more than one object a chance to handle the request."

Comment: As @Nic said, the intent here is to decoupling sender and receiver. Then, the aim of the patterns fits perfectly to the problem, imho.

Comment: btw GoF (gang of four not a typo of CoR)  :P

Comment: @riccardo.cardin & Nic decoupling the sender & receiver is an aim of lots of patterns, sharing the processing between a set of objects in chain is what makes CoR special. That's why it's call CoR :))

Comment: You can use CoR when you do not know which handlers will handle an event *a priori*. CoR has many use cases. The one you cited is one, ours is another.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin I absolutely agree that your solution would solve the problem. But what I am telling is if there's nothing to share in processing, using CoR for this is a waste. We can do it in much simpler manner. A simple EventType -> EvetHandler mapping will solve the problem. What I am trying to tell here is AFAIK we are trying to forcibly drag and drop CoR into here, which would make it worse. :))

Comment: A mapping brakes one of the requirements stated in the original questio, the fourth.

Comment: Thinking it over again, I prefer your CoR over simple Interface/Adapter. Answer deleted , +1 for you.

Comment: @Fildor, can you explain why?

Comment: Exactly the reason you gave: It's better in case of adding new EventTypes which may occur more often than I was assuming. Apart from adding one more Handler, you wouldn't need to change existing code.

Comment: The reason I didn't like it from the start is that it still needs an `instanceof` and cast in concrete implementations. I always tend to prefer solutions that do not need those.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin I accept that the question stated that it wants to avoid mapping. But what I am telling is AFAIU going with CoR would make it even worse, unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne I have update my answer. Have a look at.

Comment: @riccardo.cardin thnx a lot for your consideration. Anyway you need not to change your answer just bcoz I (or some other) raised some issues. If you really convinced with my point, that's fine. ;) Conversely, if you really believe your solution has the winning edge & points to justify, just go with it. ;) Actually IMO  the best way to do it is using polymorphism. Anyway thnx. :))

Comment: @SupunWijerathne I changed my answer because imho both solutions are a good choice, under different points of view. Often, the truth stands in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you main concern is decoupling the EventTypes from their handler I would recomend a [Chain of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

It manages decoupling by passing the EventType among a chain of potential handlers.

**Benfits**

- Reduced coupling, both handler and event have no explicit knowledge of each other
- Ability to have multiple handlers per EventType to separate concerns

**Concerns**

It is not guaranteed that there will be a handler for the event type. This may be able to be addressed with a *NotFound* handler.